# Convert shapefile to JSON by using node js

Tags: shapefile, node-js, mongodb

I want to convert a big shapefile to JSON and store it inside MongoDB. Is there any tutorial to help me? Or any library that could help.

Comment: GDAL can get you from shapefile to MongoDB, https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/mongodb.html, and you have https://www.npmjs.com/package/gdal-next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/mmomtchev/node-gdal-async

(disclaimer: I am its author)

```js
const gdal = require('gdal-async');
const ds = gdal.open('shape.shp');
for (const layer of ds.layers) {
  for (const feature of layer) {
    console.log(feature.toJSON());
  }
}
```